# Swift 4 - How can I get dateTime format to Unix format?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

Having some trouble making a function that gets the unix time from this very long date format that I get from an API.

```
func dateToUnix(date: String) -> Double {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-HH:mm"
    let utcDate = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    guard let unixTime = utcDate?.timeIntervalSince1970 else { return 0.0 }
    return unixTime
}
```

Here is the json format for the time

```
"startTime": "2018-07-10T01:00:00-05:00",
"endTime": "2018-07-10T02:00:00-05:00",
```

Comment: What's the output you're getting? How is it differing from what you expected?

Comment: You need a date format that actually matches your strings. The `-05:00` is not hour and minute, it's the timezone offset.

Comment: Also: If your dates are always in ISO 8601 format, you can just use `ISO8601DateFormatter` instead of `DateFormatter`, and then you don't have to worry about the format string at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "-05:00" is the timezone offset, not the hour and minutes.

```
func dateToUnix(string: String) -> Double {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string)
    let unixTime = date?.timeIntervalSince1970 ?? 0.0
    return unixTime
}
```

Comment: More specifically, I think "Unix epoch" time is an exact whole number of seconds (Integer), but that depends on exactly what OP is looking for.